# How can I create a web part for add update and delete operations?

Tags: web-part, development, database

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm working with web parts.

I have learned how to create a basic webpart and how to deploy it...but I don't have any ideas about how to create a web part that adds updates and deletes records from a database.

Answer (score 3):

Making a Web Part that adds, updates or deletes item from a database is just standard ASP.NET programming. For instance if you want to insert a record to a database then you probably would like to add a button to your Web Part that has a click-handler method in which you make the database operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i create one web part and add db connection and try to bind DataGrid with Database table...but when i try to add the web part to my WSS i got error 

"Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."

here is my code

Comment: This is due to the fact that you are running your Web Part under minimal trust/in the local bin of the web app (I guess). You need to add custom CAS policies. Read AC's CAS policy article on MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909485.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPGridView instead of ASP.NET GridView, and consider SharePoint to be just another database repository.